# How can I remove "Older Posts" option at the bottom of the Wordpress Home page?

Tags: css, wordpress

I want to show limited number of posts on homepage so how can I remove the option.

Comment: [Look here for tips on writing a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put "display:none" to the container and also remove the navigation script from the home page. Can you post the code of the home page, So that i can help to remove the pagination.

Comment: From which section you want to remove the the posts. Means there are many categories. Or you want each category should have limited number of posts.

Comment: I think you want to keep some limited categories in the home page. right ?

Comment: All the settings are available in the option page. Please try that or i can help you if you give me access. Thank you.

Comment: Hey actually this worked .navigation { display: none;} .....thanks a lot for helping :)